# Como mostrar un popup window por encima del layout de llamada en Android 7.0 version

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, popup

Estoy desarrollando una espécie de proveedor de contactos para usuarios de Android. La principal función es que cuando el dispositivo recibe una llamada (bloqueado o no bloqueado), aparece un popup window con cierta información del contacto que llama. El problema es que con versiones por debajo de la 7.0 de Android me funciona todo perfectamente pero a partir de Android 7.0 cuando el dispositivo está bloqueado y recibe una llamada el popupwindow aparece por detrás del layout de llamada y por lo tanto no se ve hasta que cuelgan. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar en cómo hacer que aparezca por delante del layout de llamada en Android 7.0 estaria muy agradecido.

pd. recordar que por debajo de 7.0 sí que me funciona, entonces el problema está a partir de la nueva versión 7.0
[image: La captura de pantalla es como se ve por debajo de la 7.0]

```
public class IncomingCallActivity extends Activity {
int mCurrentX = 0;
int mCurrentY = 500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final LinearLayout fondo;
    TextView text;
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_empty);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_incoming_call, null);

        Button button = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.close_window);
        text = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        button.setText("CLOSE WINDOW");

        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,mCurrentX,mCurrentY);
                popupView.bringToFront();
            }
        }, 100);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            int orgX, orgY;
            int offsetX, offsetY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        orgX = (int) (mCurrentX - event.getRawX());
                        orgY = (int) (mCurrentY - event.getRawY());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        mCurrentX = (int) event.getRawX() + orgX;
                        mCurrentY = (int) event.getRawY() + orgY;
                        popupWindow.update(mCurrentX, mCurrentY, -1, -1, true);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        String number = getIntent().getStringExtra(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        text.setText("Incoming call from " + number);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Estás en stackoverflow en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta al idioma del sitio o bien publícala en el sitio en inglés. Please translate your question.

Comment: This is a spanich comunity, pls translate your answer or publish it in https://stackoverflow.com/